# What the various ways of calling a method at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, invoke, late-binding

I need to call a method on an object but I do not know the method name until runtime.

**What are the techniques available?**

(e.g. GetMethod().Invoke(), delegates, c# 4.0 dynamic)

Thanks!

Comment: You already know what it takes.  Try to narrow the scope of your question a bit so we don't have to write a book about it.

Comment: @Hans: thanks, unfortunately I don't know all the options. After posting this question I found that I could also emit IL. At a minimum I am hoping for a list of techniques for further research. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# 4.0 `dynamic` functionality is going to be the easiest way to do this.  In a very real sense, `dynamic` is "just a wrapper" around Reflection.  It's a very *good* wrapper, though, that is probably your best option.

Other ways, in approximately increasing level of difficult:

- Using a third-party Reflection
  library.  Not sure what's out there
  these days.
- Writing your own
  Reflection code.
- Use the CodeDOM to
  create code that calls the method you
  want to call.
- Emit IL that does
  pretty much the same thing as the
  CodeDOM generated code.
- Create C#
  source code that you then compile
  into an assembly that you can call,
  which in turn calls the desired
  method.

The last three are not for the faint of heart.  Your best bet is to use `dynamic` or write your own Reflection code.  If I had had `dynamic` three years ago when I was writing code for something similar, I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to call functions that you do not know the name of until run time. Here's some doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28VS.80%29.aspx